# How can I get a list of VIN manufacturer Equipment Codes, Vehicle Descriptor Section?

Tags: database, vin

I am trying to build a VIN decoder, per paying a service will not work for my application I have found WMI data

HERE [WMI Info for all manufacturers](ftp://ftp.nhtsa.dot.gov/manufacture/)

The manufacturer.mbd

contains all WMI info

What I am looking for at this point is a Data base that contains all of the VDS info or a method to get that info and keep it up to date

Per [VIN wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number#Vehicle_descriptor_section)

I have found a list of common manufacture codes but it is out of date and incomplete

[Old VDS information](http://www.angelfire.com/ca/TORONTO/VIN/VDS.html#equip)

Basically I need a Database that has the VDS info, or the method used to query manufactures for VDS info

Comment: Did you ever find anything like this?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing, but for european market. Did you ever found anything like this ?